# ¿Por qué sweetAlert2 elimina el scroll de mi página?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Uso `SweetAlert2` y en ocasiones el modal elimina mi `Scroll` y ya no me permite desplazarme hacia el contenido en la pagina inferior.

Adjunto el código que uso

```js
Swal.fire({
        icon: "question",
        title: "¿Actualizar credenciales?",
        html: `<p>Tiempo restante.</p>
        <div class="hour"> <span id="minutes"></span> minutos / <span id="seconds"></span> segundos </div>`,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, confirmar',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar!',
        reverseButtons: true,
        allowOutsideClick: false,

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es el comportamiento esperado, si tu tienes una alerta y esta cubre toda la pantalla es normal que no puedas hacer scroll y para eso `sweetalert2` lo desactiva

Si tu alerta no es del tipo que debe cubrir toda la pantalla, pones `backdrop:false`

```js
Swal.fire({
    icon: "question",
    title: "¿Actualizar credenciales?",
    html: "algo",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, confirmar',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar!',
    reverseButtons: true,
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    backdrop: false

})
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

<script>
  //generando contenido para que aparesca el scroll
  for(let i=0; i<50;i++)
  {
    document.write(`<div>Linea ${i}</div>`);
  }
</script>
```

En todo caso siempre puedes recurrir a pisar los CSS

```js
Swal.fire({
    icon: "question",
    title: "¿Actualizar credenciales?",
    html: "algo",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, confirmar',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar!',
    reverseButtons: true,
    allowOutsideClick: false,
})
```

```css
body.swal2-shown {
    overflow: noset !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

<script>
  //generando contenido para que aparesca el scroll
  for(let i=0; i<50;i++)
  {
    document.write(`<div>Linea ${i}</div>`);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo [**este artículo**](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/678), lo podrías solucionar agregando la siguiente clase de CSS:

```
.swal2-shown {
  overflow: unset !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Si el error persiste, puedes agregar la propiedad `scrollbarPadding` y `heightAuto` de SweetAlert2, y ambos asignarlo a `false`:

```
Swal.fire({
    icon: "question",
    title: "¿Actualizar credenciales?",
    html: `<p>Tiempo restante.</p>
    <div class="hour"> <span id="minutes"></span> minutos / <span id="seconds"></span> segundos </div>`,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, confirmar',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar!',
    reverseButtons: true,
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    scrollbarPadding: false,
    heightAuto: false
})
```